# MS Edge truncating source files, Sharepoint 2016

Tags: sharepoint, internet-explorer

With the latest Edge updates this (or last) month we have experienced several issues with formatting and some JS.

Looking into it today I can see that Edge appears to be truncating some files that it downloads from the SP 2016 site.

On our main page we have a rotating slideshow that appears in IE 11 and Chrome without issue. It is completely missing in Edge.

Looking at the source of the page in Dev tools, on IE the file 'INIT.js' is 280,159 in length. Looking in Edge it is 131,074 in length and clearly cut off in the middle of a function.

I cant see any reason for this, this is on the same 1809 client. Previous clients (1703,1709 and 1803) all work fine in Edge.